# Delphi with NetBeans 7.1.2

Tags: delphi, netbeans-7

I have already installed NetBeans 7.1.2 and i am looking for Delphi plugin. Is it available at this version or in earlier ones (and which one)? Can I import delphi projects in netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

Delphi uses a proprietary compiler and framework that AFAIK is not available outside Delphi itself.

Comment: dcc32.exe is available outside the Delphi IDE

Answer (score 1):

There is only a (small) [Pascal plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nbpascal/) project for the NetBeans IDE. However it shows no progress since 2009.

However I would keep NetBeans on my hard disk, as it is a good editor for some web standard file formats (CSS, HTML) and XML / XSD files, with context-sensitive help and syntax checks, validations and so on.